# Print something every nth page

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am producing a document which will be wrapped automatically in envelopes.

For that purpose, the document needs to feature a marker every 5 pages and on its last page.

The problem is that AFAIK, XSL can't rely on  < fo:page > provided by FO.

Can anyone think of a solution?

Comment: What FO Processor are you using?

Comment: fop, I did not know it was relevant sorry for not mentioning it. By the way I have found a solution but I am limited to any given number of pages. Should I post it?

Comment: You could investigate the area tree produced as one out from FOP. (Search OP area tree sample)  It represents the composed intermediate format. This will contain page objects and you can inject your marks by manipulating the area tree and continuing the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best that I have been able to do does also require that you put enough repetitions in your `fo:page-sequence-master` to handle the maximum number of pages.

For the sake of making a smaller screenshot, this example puts a mark on every third page and on the last page:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:axf="http://www.antennahouse.com/names/XSL/Extensions"
    font-size="36pt">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm" page-width="5in" page-height="5in">
            <fo:region-body margin="36pt"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="marked" page-width="5in" page-height="5in">
            <fo:region-body margin="36pt"/>
            <fo:region-start extent="36pt"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="psm">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives maximum-repeats="2">
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="marked" page-position="last"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="spm"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="marked"/>
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives maximum-repeats="2">
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="marked" page-position="last"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="spm"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="marked"/>
            <!-- Repeat as often as necessary. -->
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives maximum-repeats="2">
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="marked" page-position="last"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="spm"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:single-page-master-reference master-reference="marked"/>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="psm">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-start">
            <fo:block margin-top="2in"><fo:external-graphic width="100%" src="logo-antenna.svg" content-width="scale-down-to-fit"/></fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block break-after="page">1</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">2</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">3</fo:block>
            <fo:block break-after="page">4</fo:block>
            <fo:block>5</fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close to my solution, only difference is that I used a repeatable page sequence for marked pages also, with a maximum-repeats of 1, because I feared these pages would be added even if not needed. Thank you for a nice and clean answer!